# $\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb N)$ is not a separable space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, lp-spaces, separable-spaces

I have to prove that $\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb N)$ is not separable.

**My attempt**

Consider a SUBSET $V$ of $\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb N)$ consisting of bounded sequences that have only $0$, $1$ entries, e.g. $(0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,\dots)$

*Now assume that this SUBSET is uncountable.*

If we take a radius $r=1/4$ then balls with origins that are elements of $V$ would be disjoint and because any base of  $\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb N)$ must contain a subset of each element of the set of these balls, base of  $\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb N)$ can't be countable so it doesnt satisfy the second axiom fo countability and thus is not separable (since  $\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb N)$ is a metric space).

Could someone check this? And I still need to prove that $V$ is uncountable...

Comment: What you have is right. A bit problematic is using the word "subspace" for $V$, since in the context of (topological) vector spaces, "subspace" usually denotes linear subspaces. Use "subset" to avoid that. Regarding the uncountability of $V$, can you draw a connection between $V$ and $\mathfrak{P}(\mathbb{N})$?

Comment: Sorry, by *separable*, do you mean that you'd like to prove that $\ell^\infty$ has no countable dense subset?  If so, it seems you're going in the wrong direction...

Comment: Exactly, no countable dense subset. Could you tell me what is wrong? thanks

Comment: Daniel, you mean connection between the power set of $N$ and $V$? Your remark about subspace vs subset is 100% correct.

Comment: Thre is no neeed to assume that your set $V$ is uncountable, for it is uncountable. You can do a standard diagonal argument to show this; notice that there is an obvious bijeection between your $V$ and the set of subsets of $\mathbb N$.

Comment: My approach would be as follows: given a countable subset $\{x_n\}$ of $\ell^\infty$, find a $y$ such that $\|y-x_n\| \geq 1$ for each $n$.

Comment: @luka5z :Don't you need finitely-many 1's in your sequence of 0's and 1s,, so that it is in $l^{\infty}$?

Comment: No. From definition $\ell ^{\infty} (\mathbb{N})$ is space of all sequences of natural numbers, such that each element of that sequence is finite.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As the OP guessed, the right subset to consider is the set $A\subset\ell^\infty$ consisting of all the sequences with zeros and ones, i.e., $\{a_n\}\in A$ if and only if
$a_n\in\{0,1\}$, for all $n$.

Clearly, if $\{a_n\},\{b_n\}\in A$ and $\{a_n\}\ne\{b_n\}$, then 
$$
\|\{a_n\}-\{b_n\}\|_\infty=1,
$$
since there exists at least one $n$, for which $a_n\ne b_n$, and hence $|a_n-b_n|=1$.

Also $|A|=\big\lvert 2^{\mathbb N}\big\rvert= 2^{\aleph_0}$. Hence $A$ is uncountable, and in fact equinumerous to $\mathbb R$.

The open sets
$$
\big\{B\big(\{a_n\},\tfrac{1}{3}\big): \{a_n\}\in A\big\},
$$
are uncountably many mutually disjoint open sets. The fact that such a collection of open sets exists means that $\ell^\infty$ is not separable.