# Prove that $l^{\infty}(\mathbb{Z^+})$ is not separable.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, lp-spaces

Let $l^{\infty}(\mathbb{Z^+})$ be the set of all bounded complex functions on  $\mathbb{Z^+}$. Then prove that $l^{\infty}(\mathbb{Z^+})$ is not separable.

My attempt: Suppose $E\subset l^{\infty}(\mathbb{Z^+})$ and $\overline E= l^{\infty}(\mathbb{Z^+})$

Each real number $t\in(0,1)$ can be expressed as $$t=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x(n)}{2^n}$$ with $x(n)=0$ or $x(n)=1$, $\forall n$

for each  $t\in(0,1)$ we can find $h(t)=x$ in  $l^{\infty}(\mathbb{Z^+})$ satisfying the above representation.Then we can find $g(x)$ in $E$ such that $${\|g(x)-x\|}_{\infty}<\frac{1}{4}$$

Let $f(t)=g(h(t))$,  $0<t<1$

Then I have proved that $f:(0,1)\to E$ is one-to-one,this proves that $E$ is uncountable. Since $E$ was arbitrary dense set,this shows that $l^{\infty}(\mathbb{Z^+})$ cannot have dense subsets which are countable.Hence $l^{\infty}(\mathbb{Z^+})$ is not separable.

My problem: Is this my proof correct? Because we do this for the set of all real valued bounded functions on $\mathbb{Z^+}$, but here I have complex valued functions.You can also share some other idea to prove this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Diagonalize. Suppose $f_1,f_2,\ldots$ is a countable dense subset. Then construct a function $f:\mathbb{Z}^+\to\{-1,1\}$. For each $n$, choose $f(n)=\pm 1$ so that $|f(n)-f_n(n)|$ is big. That way, $f$ is far from every $f_n$.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97648/why-are-l-infty-and-l-infty-non-separable-spaces, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660418/why-is-l-infty-not-separable, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702199/ell-infty-mathbb-n-is-not-a-separable-space (Maybe a few other posts can be found. You could also have a look on the list of related questions on the right.)

Comment: Since you are asking about your specific proof, I have added ([tag:proof-verification]) tag. Have a look at the [tag info](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/proof-verification/info) and if you think this tag is not suitable for your question, then edit tags to remove it.

Comment: Thank you for this new tag.

Comment: I would say that the basic idea of your proof is very similar to the proof posted in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660418/why-is-l-infty-not-separable/660422#660422). You have found an uncountable set of sequences of 0's and 1's such that distance of any two of them is 1.

Comment: [Closely related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97648/why-is-l-infty-not-separable)