# Basis for $l^{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis

As the question stated, we know that $\{e_i\}$ doesn't form a basis for $l^{\infty}$. So how can we find a basis for $l^{\infty}$, no matter it is Schauder or Hamel basis.

Answer (score 5):

Every space which has a Schauder basis is separable. We have that $\ell^\infty$ is not separable, hence it can't have a Schauder basis. You can see a proof of this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702199/ell-infty-mathbb-n-is-not-a-separable-space), for example.

Using the axiom of choice, we have that every vector space has a Hamel basis - in particular, $\ell^\infty$ has a Hamel basis, but for infinite dimensional vector spaces we usually can't exhibit one.

The $\{e_i\}$ aren't a Schauder basis for $\ell^\infty$, but they are a Schauder basis for the subspace $c_0$ of the sequences that converge to zero. For a proof of this you can see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1235687/schauder-basis-for-c-0/1334154#1334154).